# How to Read Plist Data Using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, plist

I have stored JSON data Into within Plist. Whenever I want to see my stored data I am taking path details and find into my machine then only I can see. I need to read data after storage using objective C.

```
NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves | NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
 NSDictionary *response = JSON[@"response"];
 NSArray *keys = [response allKeys];

 NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray new];
 for (NSString *key in keys) {
     NSMutableDictionary *object = response[key];
     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subject = %@",object[@"subject"]];
     NSArray *objectsWithSameSubject = [objects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
     NSInteger subjects = [object[@"subject"] integerValue];
     if (subjects > 0) {

         NSMutableArray *Objects_Subjectcount = [NSMutableArray new];
         [object setObject:Objects_Subjectcount forKey:@"Objects_Subjectcount"];
         for (NSInteger i = 0; i < subjects; i++) {
             [Objects_Subjectcount addObject:object];// object or anything you need

         }
     }
     [objects addObject:object];
 }

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsPath = paths.firstObject;
 NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"File.plist"];
 NSError *writeError = nil;
 NSDictionary *finalDict = @{@"Objects": objects};
 NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:finalDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:NSPropertyListImmutable error:&writeError];
 if(plistData){
     [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
 }
 else {
     NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  NSError *error = nil;    
    NSData * tempData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"File.plist"];
    NSPropertyListFormat plistFormat = nil;
    NSDictionary *temp = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:tempData options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 error:&error];
```

- *Note :*

  when you read data using `NSPropertyListSerialization` you dont have to pass `NSPropertyListFormat` . you either pass `nil` or pass the address for `NSPropertyListFormat`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Its throwing exception. Could you please update above code?@KDeogharkar

Comment: also I pass nil reference to variable that is pointing to memory address also check that.

Comment: NSPropertyListSerialization format error! Same error.

Comment: ohk option was wrong can you please check it now @anuska .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99133/discussion-between-kdeogharkar-and-anushka).

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the right path to the plist file, you can read it by:

```
NSMutableDictionary *plistDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

int value = [[plistDic objectForKey:@”value”] intValue];  //to get a int value for value for example
```

and to write to plist:

```
[plistDic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@”value”];

[plistDic writeToFile: path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: First I need to get all the keys

Comment: [yourDictionary allKeys] , you get an NSArray of all keys

Comment: Your code working but If I print all keyvalues Its showing empty objects. Need to get particular values and list of items

Comment: sry , i didn't get u. What r u saying >